# c2dm notification not being received

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am making an android app in which I want to show push notifications. I have implemented the code of c2dm.

But it is just giving the registration id but not showing the notifications.

I am using following code for it:

in the activity:

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0)); // boilerplate
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "andrew.housego@gmail.com");
    registrationIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gsf");
    startService(registrationIntent);
```

And in the reciever:

```
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    System.out.println("action is " + action);
    Log.w("C2DM", "Registration Receiver called");
    if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action))
        {
        Log.w("C2DM", "Received registration ID");
        registrationId = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
        String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");

        Log.d("C2DM", "dmControl: registrationId = " + registrationId + ", error = " + error);
        String deviceId = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        sendRegistrationIdToServer(deviceId, registrationId);

        }

    else if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action))

        {
        handleMessage(context, intent);
        createNotification(context, registrationId);
        }
    }


              public void createNotification(Context context, String registrationId)
    {
    URL url;
    try
        {
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification =
                new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Registration successful",
                        System.currentTimeMillis());
        String notificationTitle = "notification";
        String notificationText = "New Notification from Bingo Diary";
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, BingoDiaryActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("registration_id", registrationId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        //notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Registration",
        //      "Successfully registered", pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(99, notification);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle, notificationText, pendingIntent);


        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

CAn anyone tell me where could be  the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be with the sending side. When you send the message from the server, what do you get?